# jQuery: value undefined

Tags: jquery

i am rendering a select box using Ajax call in php   and the output is coming like

```
 <select onchange = 'addtolist(this.val)' name='select_val' id='select_val' class= 'required'>
<option  value='xzvfxcv'>xzvfxcv</option>
<option  value='dfscs'>dfscs</option>
</select>
```

ok and here is my function addtolist

```
function addtolist(id){
  alert(id);

}
```

now while changing the select box i am getting the `undefined`

please help me out out what might i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val` is not valid attribute of javascript element you have to use `value` instead,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/sNFVb/)**

```
<select onchange = 'addtolist(this.value);' name='select_val' id='select_val' class= 'required'>
     <option  value='xzvfxcv'>xzvfxcv</option>
     <option  value='dfscs'>dfscs</option>
</select>
```

Comment: please select an answer to close this question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onchange` if you want, but I think this has been largely superseded by keeping scripting together.  Get rid of `onchange` altogether and just update your JavaScript:

```
$("#select_val").on('change', function () {
   //or alert() if you must
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<select onchange = 'addtolist(this);' name='select_val' id='select_val' class= 'required'>
<option  value='xzvfxcv'>xzvfxcv</option>
<option  value='dfscs'>dfscs</option>
</select>​
```

AND

```
function addtolist(id) {
    alert(id.value);
}​
```